# Player moves figures before the game has fully appeared

Tags: typescript, browser, game-engine, phaser-framework

We're building a Phaser 3 game for a project and I have the issue that the player can move the figure before the game has fully appeared on the screen.

The game itself has loaded everything from the `preload()` function and then enters the `create()` function (I check for input in `create()`), so the order of events seems good Phaser-wise. Question is, how do I enable the input only when the browser has fully shown the game? Here's a snippet of what I mean: [video, where I spam S while the game is reloading](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82ikQsFtUAk&ab_channel=Smoothex).

When I log the events, I get a burst of logged S (down) presses in the console only when the game appears. As I said, the burst of S key presses is correct as far as its order, but I want to prevent the browser from stacking up input before Phaser checks for it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could check for input in `update()`, or, if you are using keyboard events (that you configure in `create()`) you could set a variable that stores if the game is loaded or not and in the event listener decide what to do.

I personally prefer the *"update"* version

```js
let SKey;

function create ()
{
  SKey = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
}

function update ()
{
    if (Phaser.Input.Keyboard.JustDown(SKey))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

[Here](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/input/keyboard) you can find lots of examples of how to manage keyboard inputs